# How to submit in array, only id. using Angular 7 and ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select, angular7

I submit this form:

```
let newRole = this.addForm.value
console.log(this.addForm)
```

The form is like in image:
[image]

and when I put `console.log(this.addForm.value)` show this like in [image]

I want to submit only permission_id, like this :

```
value: (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _Can you ask me any idea please?_....You meant any suggestions are welcome. Correct?

Comment: Yes @Jai Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `.map` which will return new array of `permission_id`

```
let newRole = this.addForm.value.sp_id.map(v => v.permission_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is error `ERROR TypeError: this.addForm.value.map is not a function`

Comment: did you get `this.addForm.value` before it? try to console it and share the result

Answer (score 0):

let newRole = this.addForm.value.sp_id.map((v: any) => v.permission_id);

Use this will return ids only in array

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35499791)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).